# How to deploy asp.net core project from Jenkins to Azure web app

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, asp.net-core

What steps do I need to deploy project that is built using Jenkins to Azure web app?
I currently have following steps:

- Pull sources from TFS
- `dotnet restore`
- `dotnet publish -c release` to my output folder

What should I add afterwards?